# How do I catch the event and update my page when a user accepts a request?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to invite my friends to an application using the following codes . However, I want to catch the event when the invitee accepts the request. That is as soon as the user accepots the request, I update my page by marking him as "Accepted" . I have no idea how to catch that event ..Anyone can help me out

I have the following code ;

```
function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
           message: 'You have received a pretty image from a friend.',
           data: 'some tracking info',
           title: 'Select friends to send your image to.'}, function (response) {

        if (response && response.request_ids) {

$(function(){
              //get friends who accepted the request

        } else {

               //Do something if they don't send it.

                }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once user accepts a request he is redirected to your application URL with `request_ids` GET parameter with contain ids of requests.

You can get info on request by issuing GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/USERID_REQUESTID

You shoul read [documentation on Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) for more details.